# Dell system update utility (drivers, firmware, etc)

Tags: drivers, dell-latitude

I got a new Dell E6420 yesterday and it had this really nice little utility from Dell that automatically updated firmware, bios and drivers.  However, the laptop had a 32bit version of Windows 7 so I decided to reinstall.  now I can't find that utility.  Anyone know where I can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking [Dell's support site](http://support.dell.com/support/index.aspx?~ck=pn) for software related to your model?   I did, and I believe [this is what you're looking for](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=YJDWY&FileId=2731103563).

It's called the "Dell Client System Update 1x1 Tool":

> Dell Client System Update 1x1 Tool will be installed as a Standalone
>   application on Biz. Client Supported platform to provide a Windows
>   Update Like Experience for systems software released by Dell. This
>   release of the product will support all systems supported via the PDK
>   Catalog. The current support scope is limited to all FY09+ Latitude,
>   Optiplex and Precision notebook and desktop product lines.

Under "Compatibility" it lists both your model and Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: *Exactly* what I wanted. Kudos. I think my Googlefu was weak that day :)

Comment: I rebuilt my system a few weeks ago and found myself looking for this again today.  This post was the last result on the first page of google.  None of the other results led me to a download :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this tool is not nice. It just does not work in a lot of cases on our Dell Precision M4600 with Windows 7 64 Bit. What helps is to restart the utility after the update (in case no reboot took place). But even then it detects 3 recommended updates in the first place and after successfully installing it detects another 6 updates of which 3 are the same that should have already been updated. Crap. I am talking about version 1.2.2.

Comment: I have similar behavior on occasion, but overall I would say my system is healthier as a result of using the utility.